# Errors when entering text questions

Tags: support, editing, deletion

I am a new user stackexchange. I recently set up a problem, but I'm typing text made many mistakes. Can I delete the problem and re-ask it? How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Same same on the main. And if you want to delete your question in order to re-ask it, you'd probably better directly edit it.